# Is there a way to test whether saveRDS has completed?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny dashboard for incidental use that involves loading, manipulating, and saving a 10gb file. I'd like to display a spinner while the file is being saved, just as a small precaution, since the saving process can take a minute or so. This is proving trickier than I had anticipated, because I can't seem to find any good way to hook into `saveRDS`.

As far as I can tell, once the function starts writing the file, it seems to run parallel no matter what I do, so I can't wrap it in a function that alerts me when it's finished.

There's nothing in the arguments to `saveRDS` that hints at a possible solution.

I can't use `file.exists`, because the file exists already and is overwritten.

I thought there might be a way to poll whether the connection to the file was open, but `is.open` doesn't seem to work, and I can't seem to find anything that does.

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Edit:

I'm wrong; the spinner was starting or stopping only after *everything* had been run. I am actually encountering issues with when renderUI will update on the basis of a reactive value. I know where to start looking now at least.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Manual outlier removal"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton(inputId = "saveData", label =  "Save data"),
          uiOutput("spinner")
        ),
        mainPanel()
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

#  data <- reactiveFileReader(5000, session, "Data/datacleaning.RDS", readFunc = readRDS)

  savingData <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$saveData, {
    savingData(TRUE)
    # saveRDS(data(), "Data/dc.RDS")
    Sys.sleep(5)
    savingData(FALSE)
  })


  output$spinner <- renderUI({
    if(savingData()){
      withSpinner(uiOutput("dummy"))
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Edit 2:

From the reactlog
(`Button reaction` is the observeEvent(input$saveData) that sets the reactiveVal savingData TRUE, then sleeps, then FALSE)

1. `input$saveData` has a new value (1)
2. `Button reaction` is invalidating
3. `Button reaction` removes dependency on `input$saveData`
4. `Button reaction` started calculating
5. `Button reaction` depends on `input$saveData`
6. `Button reaction` is isolating future dependencies
7. `savingData` has a new value: `logi TRUE`
8. `output$spinner` is invalidating
9. `output$spinner` removes dependency on `savingData`
10. `savingData` has a new value: `logi FALSE`
11. `Button reaction` stopped isolating future dependencies
12. `Button reaction` stopped calculating
13. `output$spinner` started calculating
14. `output$spinner` depends on `savingData`
15. `output$spinner` stopped calculating

The spinner invalidates at the right time, but does not start calculating until after the button observer stops calculating. I'm sure this is as intended, but I don't know where to start searching for solutions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That was my initial solution - `saveDone   <- reactiveVal(TRUE)` set up ahead of time, then `saveDone(FALSE); saveRDS(...); saveDone(TRUE)` but R processes them all in parallel. I can tell that the spinner works, because removing `saveDone(TRUE)` initiates a spinner that doesn't stop.

Comment: What do you mean by “processes them all in parallel”?

Comment: People have faced this problem in all kind of languages. Searching for "check if file is available" or "check if file is finished" yields a lot of results. specifically for R, maybe this one is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691335/check-if-file-is-available-not-in-use-by-another-process-with-r

Comment: @uke I think this leads down the completely wrong path: the solution you posted is complex, brittle and OS dependent; whereas in this case this is all happening *in the same process*, so the code *knows* when the `saveRDS()` call finished, because code execution only resumes after it did, not before. That’s why I’m confused what OP means with “in parallel”.

Comment: I'm intuiting that it runs in parallel (or said another way -- that it is non-blocking) because of the fact that `saveDone(TRUE)` seems to execute concurrent with `saveDone(FALSE)`. My evidence for this is that if I run them subsequently (`saveDone(FALSE); saveRDS(...); saveDone(TRUE)`), nothing happens, but I am able to trigger a spinner to start by removing`saveDone(TRUE)` and to stop by removing `saveDone(FALSE)`. I'll try to set up an MWE, but I hoped to avoid this because the problem is inextricable from `saveRDS` (other functions work) and testing the spinner requires a large file.

Comment: Okay, let’s just clear some things up: `saveRDS()` (just like all other core R functions) runs sequentially and is blocking. There are *no* non-blocking functions in R. So if this approach doesn’t work then the problem is definitely elsewhere, it is *not* due to the `saveRDS()` call.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, you're totally right. I don't know why I had convinced myself that it was working with a different function; as should be clear from my edit, this was not the case, and the problem is indeed elsewhere. I was surprised by the possibility of `saveRDS()` being non-blocking, because it ran counter to my understanding of the language, but I thought it possible that interactions with the file system might differ in some way by necessity.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158214/r-shiny-async-with-progress-bar You're probably going to want to use futures/promises to get this type of behavior.

Comment: @MrFlick I think you're right, although it seems weird that there is no way to force a flush of output, even between different `observeEvent` calls, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong. I don't want to process things asynchronously, I just want to be able to tell Shiny to flush after it's finished with one and before it starts another.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to solve this async - otherwise your app is blocked across all sessions if one session saves data. Please check my related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76005099/9841389) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71091020/how-to-show-a-loading-screen-when-the-output-is-being-calculated-in-a-background/71096495#71096495).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thank you for this comment. This is ultimately a dashboard that will only ever be used by a single person at a time (and because the editing is destructive in that it saves over the file that it loads, I have a hunch that it might be important *not* to handle it async?), but for the future, I'm glad to have these as references.

Comment: As long as you make sure, that the user can't start multiple child processes, overwriting a file isn't problematic. However, using `r_bg` to start `saveRDS` allows you to track when the process finished, which is what you need, I think (the same can be done with [promises](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/promises/versions/1.2.1/topics/then)).

Comment: Of course, if you don't want to go async, you can use `callr::r()` instead of `r_bg()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out already your problem has nothing to do with `saveRDS` being run in parallel (which it doesn't), but with the flow of your app:

1. You click a button, which sets `savingData` to `TRUE`.
2. In the **same** observer, you start a lengthy process.
3. After the lengthy process finsihes, you set `savingData` back to `FALSE`
4. Now that the first observer has finished (but **not** in between) any other observer has the chance to fire. A candidate would be the `render` function, but, alas, `savingData` is not `TRUE` anymore, so it does not fire.
5. That is, the `render`Function would only fire after the `observer` finishes, which it only does **after** the lengthy operation is done. Hence, you do not see any loader, because it cannot fire while another observer is still running, and afterwards it won't run, because the lengthy process is anyways already done.

Having said that, there is an easy solution. Instead of mis-using `withSpinner` (the idea is that it adds a loading animation to an output while it is being rendered, but you do not really want to show an output, you use an output simply to make the spinner work), you can use another library `shinybusy` which allows to start a loading animation either on each busy cycle or manually, and the latter is what you want:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(shinybusy)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Manual outlier removal"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      use_busy_spinner("fading-circle", position = "full-page"),
      actionButton(inputId = "saveData", label =  "Save data"),
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$saveData, {
    show_spinner()
    Sys.sleep(5)
    hide_spinner()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```